# Is it possible to allow write access to an Excel file on Teams channel files only through a Power Automate Flow?

Tags: excel, automation, office365, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I could not find information about this. My guess is that it is not possible but maybe there is a clever workaround.

Basically, a Team will be using some forms made with Adaptive Cards on Power Automate. The information is posted in a channel and also sent to an Excel file. I realized of course users need write access to the file. But I don't want them snooping around the file or changing it, deleting, etc. I want them to just have write access through that particular Power Automate flow. Is this doable?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a service account in the connection of the Excel actions? This might be a way of still able to interact with the file from within the flow while not giving other users access to the file?

Comment: I'm aware of service accounts in the context of shared mailboxes. How would that work with Power automate? One thing I wanted to keep is the identity of the OP who posts on the channel. By having their personal account linked to the flow I get their identity easily on Excel and on the channel. Maybe allowing them access to the flow using a service account would remove this ability to identify them which would be undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

The flow will be created and run under the context you create it in, not under the context of the user who interacted with the Adaptive Card, so that means it can be set to write to the Excel file no problem. What you -will- get on the Adaptive Card response Action is user info - Display Name, Email, etc., which you can use to log to the Excel file or whatever.

Comment: The user who initiates the action of opening the adaptive card form and then submitting the information needs to have write/edit access to that excel file otherwise, there will be an error in the workflow. This only started to work with no errors after I shared the file with write permissions with the users. I was wondering if there is some kind of action I can place between "From the compose box" and "Add a row into a table" which takes away the user ID and writes to the Excel file as a Powerautomate Bot or anonymously or as the owner of the flow. This way I could remove access from the users

Comment: How does the flow get initiated, and what Action are you using to write to Excel?

Comment: If you're using the "Add a row into a table" action, then next to the title, on the right, are 3 dots like this: "...". Click on it to open the menu, and under "Connection references" you should be able to choose/modify the user account being used to write to the Excel file

Comment: Check the image I posted above under "EDIT". User composes message on Teams via Workflows and submits. Action is "Add row into a table".